# How to Export dataFrame of Dataframe to Excel that is compact and looks nice?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I am trying to export a pandas DataFrame consisting of DataFrames into and excel file that looks good and is intuitive to look at. But I am stuck with how the to_excel method, even if given startrow and startcol rewrites the entire sheet, even if it could leave prewritten data intact. I was able to export one day of the data I would like to print out in a way that looks like I would like a day to look, or the complete data looking like a mess, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the output right.
This is the output of one day done correctly:

```
Writer=ExcelWriter(path, "xlsxwriter")
for weekindex, week in enumerate(WeekList):
    for dayindex, day in enumerate(week):
        for exercise in week[day]:
            exercise.to_excel(Writer, sheet_name=f"Week {weekindex+1}", index=False, header=True, merge_cells=False)
Writer.close()
```

This is a week output (but it looks horrible, as it crams every exercise in a day in a cell)

```
for weekindex, week in enumerate(WeekList):
    for day in week:
        week.to_excel(Writer, sheet_name=f"Week {weekindex+1}", index=True, header=True, merge_cells=False)
Writer.close()
```

What I would recreate is something like the following code, using prettytables (but that cannot be output to excel):

```
DailyTableList=[]
WeeklyTable=PrettyTable()
WeeklyTable.set_style(ORGMODE)
WeeklyTable.field_names=Days
for week in WeeksOfProgram:
    for day in week.ProgramDays:
        DailyTable = PrettyTable()
        DailyTable.set_style(ORGMODE)
        DailyTable.field_names=["Exercise", "Sets", "Reps", "PercentageOfOneRepMax","INOL"]
        for index, exercise in enumerate(day.ExerciseList):
            DailyTable.add_row([exercise.Name, exercise.NumberOfSets, exercise.NumberOfReps, exercise.Intensity, exercise.INOL])
            if(index % windowsize == windowsize - 1 or index==len(day.ExerciseList)-1):
                #print(DailyTable)  only here for debugging purposes          
                DailyTableList.append(deepcopy(DailyTable))
                DailyTable.clear_rows()
    WeeklyTable.add_row(DailyTableList)
    DailyTableList.clear()
print(WeeklyTable)
```

So I would like to create a table with each cell being a separate day, each day listing the day's exercises.

I tried setting startrow and startcol, but the whole worsheet is overwritten no matter what I tried. Shoul I maybe use the xlsxwriter natively? I tried that once, but gave up because it was a huge pain in the neck but maybe that's the best solution?

The whole repo is available under this link: github.com/NimbleCapricorn/WorkoutRoutineGenerator

Its completely open source, so I am not profiting off of this whatsoever

Comment: Please share sample data on OP.

Comment: Added. I did not know whether linking to the repo is allowed, but its completely open source, and I am not profiting off of it, so maybe its OK? (I am sorry, I am not a great software developer, so the code is quite messy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was changing the perspective: instead of storing the data as dataframe of dataframe, each week was a list of exercises. The exercises had a new attribute, named Day, which stored which day these exercises were to be performed. The output is not the same as the one I desired, but it has its own advantages, and are vastly easier both to create, and to output.

```
#DataFrame implementation        
path=f"{os.getcwd()}/Output.xlsx"
WeekList=[]
for weekindex, week in enumerate(WeeksOfProgram):
    OneWeek=DataFrame(data={"Day":[], "Exercise":[], "Sets":[], "Reps":[], "PercentageOfOneRepMax":[], "INOL":[]})
    for dayindex, day in enumerate(week.ProgramDays):
        for index, exercise in enumerate(day.ExerciseList):
            OneWeek=concat([OneWeek, DataFrame([[day.Name, exercise.Name, exercise.NumberOfSets, exercise.NumberOfReps, exercise.Intensity, exercise.INOL ]], columns=OneWeek.columns)], ignore_index=True)
    WeekList.append(deepcopy(OneWeek))

Writer=ExcelWriter(path, "xlsxwriter")
Book=Writer.book
Format=Book.add_format({'align': 'center', 'valign': 'vcenter', 'border': 2})
for weekindex, week in enumerate(WeekList):
        week.to_excel(Writer, sheet_name=f"Week {weekindex+1}", index=False, header=True, merge_cells=True)
Writer.close()
```

With formatting, this will output an even better version of what I tried to do.